# Why I am not able to restore DB from backup after it is detached?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got a weird situation.
I have a database by name xyz. I detached the database. So the data and log files are still there in the corresponding folders. When I try to restore database from the backup thru SQLAgent job, its failing to restore. I used Move and Replace options in TSQL too. But if I restore thru Query Analyzer the same TSQL working fine.

If the database is there (without detaching), the job is overwriting successfully... Why it is like that? I added both SQLService and SQL Agent accounts as Local Admins to the machine to overwrite the data and log files.

I am getting this error when the job fails...Restore Databases:Error: The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\XXXXXX.mdf'.

Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I added both SQLService and SQL Agent accounts as Local Admins to the machine to overwrite the data and log files.

This does not implicitly allow both service users to access the DATA folder. (e.g. an Administrator does not have direct access to user home folders) Have you checked the explicit permissions for the DATA folder and / or the .mdf and .ldf files?

I would guess the following: (Haven't found any docs...)

When a database is attached, the SQL Agent can use the Windows security context from the database engine, which is able to access the DATA folder and all files. When it is detached and the agent tries to restore the database, it needs to acces the DATA folder with its own security context and does not have the appropriate NTFS permissions.

I would check the permissions for the DATA folder and the .mdf / .ldf files for the User the Agent is using. e.g. "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT"

That would explain, why the sql script is working, when executed manually (in security context of the database engine.) Kind of Schroedingers SQL Job...